Coroutines test when two events are emitted and a state is set and reset
Code to Test
fun updateAccount() {
    coroutineScope.launch {
        startLoading()
        val isAccountUpdated = updateAccountUseCase()
        if (isAccountUpdated) {
            navigator.navigateUp()
        } else {
            completeLoading()
            // TODO: Show Error
        }
    }
}

For context
val refreshSignal: MutableSharedFlow<Unit> = MutableSharedFlow(
    replay = 0,
    extraBufferCapacity = 1,
)
fun startLoading() {
    isLoading = true
    refreshSignal.tryEmit(Unit)
}
fun completeLoading() {
    isLoading = false
    refreshSignal.tryEmit(Unit)
}

Successful test
@Test
fun `updateAccount when updateAccountUseCase returns true`() = testScope.runTest {
    whenever(updateAccountUseCase()).thenReturn(true)

    SUT.refreshSignal.test {
        SUT.updateAccount()

        assertEquals(Unit, awaitItem())
        assertEquals(true, SUT.isLoading)
        verify(navigator).navigateUp()
        expectNoEvents()
    }
}

Failing test
@Test
fun `updateAccount when updateAccountUseCase returns false`() = testScope.runTest {
    whenever(updateAccountUseCase()).thenReturn(false)

    SUT.refreshSignal.test {
        SUT.updateAccount()

        assertEquals(Unit, awaitItem())
        assertEquals(true, SUT.isLoading) // This assertion fails as the isLoading is reset by this time
    
        assertEquals(Unit, awaitItem())
        assertEquals(false, SUT.isLoading)
        expectNoEvents()
    }
}


Additional info on debugging attempts,

Tried using yield() and delays().

yield() did not work.
When using delay(),
If prod code is modified like this,
fun updateAccount() {
    coroutineScope.launch {
        startLoading()
        delay(100) // Added delay here
        val isAccountUpdated = updateAccountUseCase()
        if (isAccountUpdated) {
            navigator.navigateUp()
        } else {
            completeLoading()
            // TODO: Show Error
        }
    }
}

And test methods are modified like these,
@Test
fun `updateAccount when updateAccountUseCase returns true`() = testScope.runTest {
    whenever(updateAccountUseCase()).thenReturn(true)

    SUT.refreshSignal.test {
        SUT.updateAccount()

        assertEquals(Unit, awaitItem())
        assertEquals(true, SUT.isLoading)
        advanceUntilIdle()  // Added this advance
        expectNoEvents()
    }

    
    verify(navigator).navigateUp()
}

@Test
fun `updateAccount when updateAccountUseCase returns false`() = testScope.runTest {
    whenever(updateAccountUseCase()).thenReturn(false)

    SUT.refreshSignal.test {
        SUT.updateAccount()

        assertEquals(Unit, awaitItem())
        assertEquals(true, SUT.isLoading) 

        advanceUntilIdle() // Added this advance
        assertEquals(Unit, awaitItem())
        assertEquals(false, SUT.isLoading)
        expectNoEvents()
    }
}


I'm not sure if I understand your example correctly, but it feels you expected the producer to somehow wait for the consumer, so only after we consume an item from the flow, the isLoading value changes. In reality, producer and consumer run concurrently. In the second example the producer calls startLoading then almost immediatelly it calls completeLoading. At the time the consumer gets the first item, producer already went through both functions. But this execution order is probably not guaranteed - it is a race condition between the producer and the consumer.
It feels very strange that you use flows and at the same time you share a mutable state (isLoading). One of the main points of using frameworks like flows is to avoid sharing mutable states as this is error prone and results in problems like above.
Typical solution would be to emit the boolean using the flow. I don't provide a fully working example as you probably know about such solution and for some reason you made a decision to not use it.

I tried using flows for managing all such states, but it led to a large number of flows. This resulted in the need to combine multiple flows, manage their event collection, and handle updates. As I added more states, this approach became difficult to scale.
